# How to extract 2 strings in one line and compare it by using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have lots of txt files and each of the file has below contents.
And I want to compare Run with Passed value.
e.g. 00001A22 vs 00001A22

I can use excel for those works but I have more than 200 files.
It's a big job.

And I try to use powershell to build a script to extract 2 strings and compare it. I tried to select string but I failed.
Is there any method to work?

```
  DRAM Test             Run: 00001A22     Passed: 00001A22 
  Ethernet Test         Run: 000011E2     Passed: 000011E2 
  DRAM Test             Run: 00001BA7     Passed: 00001BA7
  Ethernet Test         Run: 000012EC     Passed: 000012EC 
  DRAM Test             Run: 00001CA3     Passed: 00001CA3 
  Ethernet Test         Run: 00001399     Passed: 00001399
```

Comment: what does 00001A22 vs 00001A22 means? Are you trying to search a string inside a file?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regex pattern with named capture groups for this:

```
# Define pattern that captures the hex strings
$CaptureTestPattern = 'Run: (?<run>[0-9A-F]{8}).*Passed: (?<passed>[0-9A-F]{8})'

# Go through each line in file
Get-Content tests.txt |ForEach-Object {
    # Check if string contains both a "run" and "passed" result
    if(($m = [regex]::Match($_,$CaptureTestPattern)).Success)
    {
        # Compare them
        if($m.Groups['run'].Value -eq $m.Groups['passed'])
        {
            # they are the same!
        }
        else
        {
            # they are NOT the same!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use a Regex too, with the match operator, your code is more readable than my one line.

Comment: OP wanted a oneliner tho, still i think this one is better

Comment: He can wrap the above in a function and make his own "one-liner" ;) Technically I'm relying on a single pipeline, I'd argue that counts as a one-liner

Answer (score 0):

According the fact the file test.txt contains the following :

```
DRAM Test Run: 00001A22 Passed: 00001A22
Ethernet Test Run: 000011E2 Passed: 000011E2
DRAM Test Run: 00001BA7 Passed: 00001BA7
Ethernet Test Run: 000012EC Passed: 000012ED
DRAM Test Run: 00001CA3 Passed: 00001CA3
Ethernet Test Run: 00001399 Passed: 00001399
```

You can use :

```
Get-Content D:\Temp\test.txt | % {$n=0}{$_ -match '^.*Run: (.*) Passed: (.*)$' | Out-Null; if ($Matches[1] -ne $Matches[2]){"line $n KO"}; $n++}
```

it returns

```
line 3 KO
```